# Adding a dictionary definition

Tags: formatting, automation

Does anyone know of a package that supports dictionary definitions? I was thinking of something like this:

[image]

Source: Luscombe et al (2001), Yearbook of Medical Informatics.

A) the easiest would probably be to type it in yourself and stick it in a parbox

B) nicer would be to be able to link it in from a dictionary file

C) even better would be to link it in and to just call it with the correct formatting

Comment: If you want the sorting to be done automatically you could try [glossaries](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) or `datagidx` (part of [datatool](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool)). The latter comes with [a dictionary example](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datatool/samples/sample-dict.tex) however `datagidx` is much slower at sorting than `glossaries` (via `xindy`/`makeindex`). Also check out http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/bytopic.html#dictio

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know a package, but I did write some lines of code, which will be given as a compilable example in the end. A short explaination of its functionality first:

1. As desired, you will have a database which can be fed with various dictionary definitions. The form is: `\dictdef[prefix=<>, caption=<>]{Def'ed Term}{Dictionary}{Def' text}`, where the prefix-key is setting information preeceding the entry and the caption-key allows you to give an alternative name to the definition. In the definition text itself you can use `\dictemph{<some text>}` to highlight words of the definition, if needed.
2. Declare a shorthand for a dictionary with `\dictshorthand{<shorthand>}{<full name>}`.
3. You can include a definition in the document body by calling `\dictcite{Dictionary}{Term}`.
4. You can influence the styling with `\dictsetup{defsep=<>, dictwidth=<>, dictskip=<>, prefixfont=<>, notefont=<>, dictemph=<>, alignment=<>, note=<>}`. If the keys are not self-explanatory just leave a comment. (Note, that all the keys will take LaTeX compliant lengths declarations or macro names - leaving the escape char, except the last ones, which are able to take the values *center/right/left* (for 'alignment') or boolean values (*true/false* 'for note').)

### The Code

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{keyval}          %Required for the solution
    \usepackage{etoolbox}        %idem
    \usepackage{ulem}            %idem
    \usepackage{csquotes,lipsum}

    \makeatletter
    \newif\if@DICT@note
      \@DICT@notetrue
    \let\DICT@defsep=:
    \let\DICT@prefixfont=\itshape
    \let\DICT@termfont=\bfseries
    \let\DICT@notefont=\itshape
    \let\DICT@alignment\raggedright
    \let\dictemph=\uline
    \newlength{\dictskip}
    \newlength{\dictwidth}
    \newlength{\DICT@innerwidth}
      \setlength{\dictskip}{1em}
      \setlength{\dictwidth}{\textwidth}
      \AtBeginDocument{%
        \addtolength{\dictwidth}{-7pt}
        \setlength{\DICT@innerwidth}{\dictwidth}
        \addtolength{\DICT@innerwidth}{-.5em}
      }
    \define@key{dictsetup}{defsep}{\gdef\DICT@defsep{#1}}
    \define@key{dictsetup}{prefixfont}{\expandafter\let\csname DICT@prefixfont\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname}
    \define@key{dictsetup}{notefont}{\expandafter\let\csname DICT@notefont\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname}
    \define@key{dictsetup}{dictemph}{\expandafter\let\csname dictemph\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname}
    \define@key{dictsetup}{alignment}{%
      \def\@tempa{#1}
      \ifdefstring{\@tempa}{center}
        {\let\DICT@alignment\centering}{%
        \ifdefstring{\@tempa}{left}
          {\let\DICT@alignment\raggedright}{%
          \ifdefstring{\@tempa}{right}
            {\let\DICT@alignment\raggedleft}{%
              \@latex@error{The option #1 does not exist for the alignment-key}\@ehc
            }
          }
        }
      }
    \define@key{dictsetup}{note}{%
      \def\@tempa{#1}
      \ifdefstring{\@tempa}{true}
        {\@DICT@notetrue}{%
        \ifdefstring{\@tempa}{false}
          {\@DICT@notefalse}{
            \@latex@warning{The note-key does only accept boolean values}\@ehc
          }    
        }
      }
    \define@key{dictsetup}{dictskip}{\setlength{\dictskip}{#1}}
    \define@key{dictsetup}{dictwidth}{\setlength{\dictwidth}{#1}}
      \newcommand{\dictsetup}[1]{\setkeys{dictsetup}{#1}}
    \define@key{dict}{caption}{\gdef\DICT@caption{#1}}
    \define@key{dict}{prefix}{\gdef\DICT@prefix{{(\DICT@prefixfont #1)}}}
    %\define@key{dict}{label}{\label{dict:#1}}
      \newcommand{\dictshorthand}[2]{\@namedef{DICT@#1@sh}{#2}}
    \newcommand{\dictdef}[4][]{%
      \setkeys{dict}{#1}
        \expandafter\let\csname #3#2caption\endcsname\DICT@caption
        \expandafter\let\csname #3#2prefix\endcsname\DICT@prefix
        \expandafter\gdef\csname #3@#2\endcsname{#2}
        \expandafter\gdef\csname #3#2body\endcsname{#4}
      \expandafter\gdef\csname DICT@#3#2\endcsname{%
        \ifcsname #3#2prefix\endcsname\protect\@nameuse{#3#2prefix}\space\fi
        \ifcsname #3#2caption\endcsname
          \protect\@nameuse{#3#2caption}
        \else
          {\DICT@termfont\protect\@nameuse{#3@#2}}
        \fi
        \unskip\DICT@defsep\space
        \protect\@nameuse{#3#2body}
      }
    }
    \newcommand*{\dictcite}[2]{%
      \par\vskip\dictskip
      \vbox{
      \DICT@alignment
      \par\noindent\fbox{\parbox{\dictwidth}{\centering\parbox{\DICT@innerwidth}{\@nameuse{DICT@#1#2}}}}\par
      \if@DICT@note{\DICT@notefont\smallskip \noindent(\submsntext\space\@nameuse{DICT@#1@sh})\par}\fi
      }
    }
    \newcommand{\submsntext}{As submitted to the}
    \newcommand{\dictlibrary}[1]{\input{#1.ddx}}
    \makeatother

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %A small test
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    %Uncomment the next line to see the style changes caused by \dictsetup
    %\dictsetup{defsep={.}, dictwidth=10cm, dictskip=2em, prefixfont=scshape, notefont=sffamily, dictemph=textit, alignment=center}
    \dictshorthand{OED}{Oxford English Dictionary}
    \dictlibrary{mylib}

    \begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-2]%to visualize the skip before the dictionary definition
    \dictcite{OED}{Bioinformatics}
    \end{document}
```

And, last but not least, the database `mylib.ddx` (I chose this file extension for the case that I add a script for an easier handling of the database.):

```
\dictdef[prefix=Molecular, caption=\textbf{Bio}-Informatics]{Bioinformatics}{OED}
{Bioinformatics is conceptualising biology in terms of molecules (in the sense of physical chemistry) and applying \enquote{\dictemph{informatics techniques}} (derived from disciplines such as applied maths, computer science and statistics) to \dictemph{understand} and \dictemph{organise} the \dictemph{information} associated with these molecules, on a \dictemph{large scale}. In short, bioinformatics is a management information system for molecular biology and has many \dictemph{partial applications}.}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Very nice solution... and congrats to jump over 10k ;-)

Comment: oh thank you @ChristianHupfer thats very kind of you! And yes!!!! 10k :)